# jquery multiple selectors in print function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Html:

```
<div id="firstline">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <a href="/"><div id="logo">Flooring</div></a>
    </div>
 ...
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <ul>
    ...
      <li>
        <button id="printall"><b class="fa fa-print"></b> Print</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="detailarea" class="col-md-12">
...
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
...
 $("#printall").click(function(){
    $('#logo, #firstshow, #detailarea').print();
 });
});
```

I am trying to print the above id's alltogether in the same page but it reconizes only the first id #logo and prints only the logo. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $("#printall").click(function(){ 
    var printThis = $('<div/>');
    $('#logo').clone().appendTo(printThis);
    $('#firstshow').clone().appendTo(printThis);
    $('#detailarea').clone().appendTo(printThis);
    $(printThis).print();
});
```

But this won't clone any dynamic content, like if they've entered text somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to create a new page, then append the content of the containers you want to print, then print it.

Something like:

```
$("#printall").click(function(){

    $('#logo, #firstshow, #detailarea').each(function(){
         $('#new-container').append($(this).html());
    });

    $('#new-container').print();
});
```

Comment: It should be worked but it didn't. Now in print window shows all my divs in page not that 3 selected.

Answer (score 0):

try in jquery:

```
$("#printall").click(function(){
    $('#logo, #firstshow, #detailarea').each(function(){
       $(this).print();
    };
});
```

Comment: Yes I tryed that before ... I need that divs in one page. That code work only and open seperate 3 print windows one div for each.